# A valid SQL-command won't run in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I ran the following code in PHPAdmin's terminal:

```
SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM User
WHERE email = 'ijp'
```

and got result 0.

Then part of my PHP program goes as follows:

```
$email = clean_input($_POST['email']);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE '.$email.'=email"; 
echo $query;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
echo $result;
mysqli_close($link);
```

I have checked that I logging into the database went fine. Still the output is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE email='ijp'
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string   in .../html/register.php on line 49
```

How can I run MySQL-commands in PHP?

Comment: And you're certain that you *have* rows where the `email` column contains `ijp` exactly?

Comment: I don't have such rows but I'm just wondering why it won't output 0?

Comment: You may want to `echo mysqli_error($link);` and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value or `$email` is `'ijp'`, the value of `$query` after

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE '.$email.'=email";
```

Would be...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE ijp=email
```

Use `'$email'` instead of `'.$email.'`

Answer (score 5):

You are passing the `$result` resource to `echo` which expects a string. You need to use one of the `mysqli_fetch_*` functions to read the value from the `$result` and then print it.

`mysqli_fetch()` is deprecated, use `mysqli_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_all`, for example:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
    echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    echo mysqli_fetch($result);  outputs Warning: mysqli_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean ...

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE email=\"".$email."\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

all the above answers are all correct but one thing was ommited... you need to differentiate between a table called "User" and one called "user" - they are case-sensitive on *NIX systems (Linux and the like)